# How to emulate mouseenter and mouseleave DOM events for old browsers?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent

Making a window with a div and using mouseover - mouseout has the known issue: if there is a child div inside, it will fire mouseout. This were recently solved by mouseenter and mouseleave because doesn't fire unless the mouse point go out the root div, the real window. Unfortunately, there is a lot of browsers the wont recognize those new events, as shown in [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html). :

- FireFox 7
- Chrome 14
- Safari 5.1

I think it might be possible to use event bubbling handling with mouseover and mouseout to produce the desired effect. Is it possible? Is there another (better) way? Or it just can't be done?

Obs.: not using jQuery in this project.

EDIT: my code for testing:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Mouse Events Tester</title>
<script>
var inside = function(e){
    console.log("I am inside!");
}

var outside = function(e){
    if(e.target !== this) console.log("Now outside...");
}

function targetOnly(handler) {
    return function (e) {
        if (e.target === this)
            return handler.apply(this, arguments);
        return;
    };
}

function ini(){
    document.getElementById("win").addEventListener("mouseover", inside, false);
    document.getElementById("win").addEventListener("mouseout", outside, false);
}


</script>
</head>

<body onload="ini();">
<div id="win" style="border:#000 solid 2px; background-color:#999;">
    <p>Window</p>
    <div id="anything" style="border:#000 dashed 1px; background-color:#CCC;">
    <p>An object inside the window</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at `e.target` and compare it to `this`, if `e.target !== this`, the event is coming from a child node

Comment: Do you have a reason to support these old browsers?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: I'm using Safari 5.1 to develop, things got to work for me at list, right?

Comment: @PaulS.: Interesting! Why didn't you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent like an hour on this and I came out with this code:

```
Element.prototype.childOf = function(p){var c=this;while((c=c.parentNode)&&c!==p);return !!c};

el = document.getElementById('your-element-id');

el.onmouseover = function(e) {
    if (e.target == e.currentTarget && !e.fromElement.childOf(e.currentTarget) && !e.toElement.childOf(e.currentTarget)) {
        // you are in
    }
}

el.onmouseout = function(e) {
    if (e.target == e.currentTarget && !e.fromElement.childOf(e.currentTarget) && !e.toElement.childOf(e.currentTarget)) {
        // you are out
    }
}
```

Comment: It seams will do the job. I'll wait for other answers because I mentioned bubbles, let's see if somebody got something to say about.

Comment: @GustavoPinent Capturing and Bubbling are just representing the direction of the event propagation, they have nothing to do with this kind of problem...

Comment: I tested this morning and it has an interesting effect: when get into an inside div (up a level), it didn't fire, but when it come back to root div, it fire (and it shouldn't). I think the solution will be more complicated a bit.

Comment: changing your expression by this: "!(e.target.id==e.currentTarget.id)" has solved half of the problem. It still fire when mouse is coming back from an inside DIV, however, the mouseover will fire too, so it can be managed. You might try and fix your answer.

Comment: @GustavoPinent I edited my code and I want an award for this because I really lost an hour trying to achieve this result, ahahah. Now it works.

Comment: Ok, ok, you deserve! I was thinking about this: a recursive verification if the target is inside the currentTarget. I'll probably make a generic solution to be used when needed. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the Element.prototype.childOf that I've defined in the first line does exactly what you want, but without recursion.  It does a while loop that goes up until it finds the parent element that you want and then outputs true or false. You can do it even with event.target like this: event.target.childOf(event.currentTarget). If true the target is a children of currentTarget.

Comment: I understood, what I meant is to think about a bigger picture (my own) after solved the test. I did a method for Elements called "hasChild" by Object.defineProperty to be a part of my library and be improved, if needed, in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Using `event.target` you can see from which *Node* an *Event* `e` originated from. If you'll need to check things like this often it might be easiest if you write a function wrapper which only invokes your `handler` if `e.target === this`

```
function targetOnly(handler) {
    return function (e) {
        if (e.target === this)
            return handler.apply(this, arguments);
        return;
    };
}

foo.addEventListener('mouseover', targetOnly(handerA));
foo.addEventListener('mouseout' , targetOnly(handerB));
```

---

MDN page for [`event.target` **here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target)

Answer (score -2):

add an invisible div as child with display:none, when the mouseover is triggered, display the the invisible div, trigger mouseout with the invisible div,
something like this.

```
    <div id="parent" onmouseover="functionover()" >
        <div id="child1" onmouseout="functionout()"
         style='position:absolute;display:none;width:100%;height:100%;'"></div>
        <div id="yourchildelement" ></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function functionover()
    {
    $('#child1').css('display','block');
    ....
    }
    </script>
```

something like this, hope this helps...

Comment: I'm not using jQuery in this project.